# Android sqlite rounding numbers without request

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a simple sqlite table created with:

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE tab1("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "amount NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"
                + ");";

db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
```

But when I insert values into the table they get rounded:

```
INSERT INTO tab1(amount) VALUES (123456789.12) // Becomes 1.23457e+08
INSERT INTO tab1(amount) VALUES (12345.67)     // Becomes 12345.7
INSERT INTO tab1(amount) VALUES (300087.59)    // Becomes 300088
INSERT INTO tab1(amount) VALUES (3000001.22)   // Becomes 3e+06
```

How can I save the full number into the table and still be able to use queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE amount < 0
```

Edit:

@MikeT thanks for your sugestion, I was using the Cursor getString method.
Now I'm using the getDouble method and then converting to BigDecimal and  rounding, it solved the problem.

Comment: `amount TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your issue is how you are extracting the values, rather than how they are stored.

It would appear that you are using the Cursor `getString` method.

Try using the Cursor `getFloat` or `getDouble` methods instead.

The following (extracted from [How flexible/restricive are SQLite column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types)) shows you the results of the various Cursor `get????` methods (*except the exception from `getBlob` has been trapped and handled* ) :-

For `Double myREAL = 213456789.4528791134567890109643534276;` :-

```
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes: Column=REAL_COL<<
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes:  VALUE AS INT >>213456789<<
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes:  VALUE AS LONG >>213456789<<
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes:  VALUE AS STRING >>2.13457e+08<<
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes:  VALUE AS DOUBLE >>2.134567894528791E8<<
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes:  VALUE AS FLOAT >>2.1345678E8<<
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes:  VALUE AS SHORT >>6037<<
08-08 09:19:03.658 13575-13575/mjt.soqanda D/ColTypes:      Unable to handle with getBlob.
```

SQlite is very flexible with regard to storing values. In short any value of can be stored in any column type and each row/column has it's own unique type.

You may wish to have a read of [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: I'm using the 'getDouble' method now. It works, but after geting it I convert to bigdecimal and round, otherwise I would get some small errors like 2,09999999.... instead of 2,10.