# SQLite numeric data types (work with REAL or DOUBLE)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

wehenever I look at tutorials about SQLite, I always see that values like INT or STRINGs (TEXT, VARCHAR) are used. How do I use DOUBLE, for example?
I create a table with a value DOUBLE and I want to insert a value DOUBLE from an EditText. Whenever I try, my app crashes, why?

Comment: Could you post your code and LogCat?

Comment: Mind to google for `sqlite data types`?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use DOUBLE, for example?

The **column type** *(e.g. INT VARCHAR DOUBLE even RUMPLESTILTSKIN would be accepted as a column type e.g. `CREATE TABLE mytable  (data1 RUMPLESTILTSKIN)`)* **doesn't really matter**.

This is due to the **flexibility** of SQLite column types as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types), which also references [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

To store a double just store it as a string (or a double passed via `ContentValues` when using the SQLiteDatabase `insert` method), e.g. based upon `yourEditText.getText().toString()` and retrieve it as double using the Cursor's `getDouble` method. The link above has examples of how `getDouble` works i.e. it will always return a double (*except if the data has been stored as a BLOB, in which case an exception occurs (trapped in the examples in the link)*).

Examples (where db is an SQLiteDatabase):-

1 Using execSQL and SQL

```
// Not recommended
String sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (yourdoublecolum) VALUES(" + youredittext.getText.toString() + ")";
db.execSQL(sql);
```

2 Using SQLitedatabase `insert` method with string

```
// Not recommended
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("yourdoubleccolumn", youredittext.getText.toString());
long insertedid = db.insert("yourtable",null,cv);
```

3 Using SQLitedata `insert` method with double

```
// Better but still potential for exception when parsing so
// need to ensure that youredittext is acceptable.
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("yourdoubleccolumn", Double.parseDouble(youredittext.getText.toString()));
long insertedid = db.insert("yourtable",null,cv);
```