# displaying the value of a particular row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to **display value of a particular row** in android to check if a particular updation. Can I made it successful or not? But as the return type is `cursor` **I don't know  how to fetch it**. So pls help me.

```
public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from calls where id=" + id + "", null);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: what you want to return??

Comment: I want to see the value of a each field in the row with the particular id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get row value as a String. Then return string value.

```
public String getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from calls where id=" + id + "", null);    
        if (res.getCount() > 0) {
            res.moveToFirst();
            String s = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("id"));
return s;
}
```

Comment: let me try on monday when I am at office.

Comment: no i tried the above one and it worked.anyways thanks

Comment: You are welcome user8601021. Its pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

call your method to get data as arraylist of hashmap

```
dataList.addAll(loginDataBaseAdapter.getData(id));
```

or

```
dataList = loginDataBaseAdapter.getData(id);
```

in db_class

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getData(String id) {
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> returnArray = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from calls where id=" + id + "", null);

if (res != null && res.getCount() > 0) {
 if (res.moveToLast()) {
    do {
       HashMap<String, String> getdatamap = new HashMap<String, String>();
         getdatamap.put("KEY_ONE", res.getString(1));
         getdatamap.put("KEY_TWO, res.getString(2));

         returnArray.add(getdatamap);
       }while (res.moveToPrevious());
   }
 }
 res.close();
 return returnArray;
}
```

Now you can use the values in arraylist to make your view

Comment: let me try on monday when I am at office.

Comment: the above answer is a much easier one.But Thanks for responding

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from calls where id=" + id + "", null);
if (res != null) {
    res.moveToFirst();
}
String firstColumnValue = res.getString(0);
String secondColumnValue = res.getString(1);
```

And **close** the database after retrieving values:

```
db.close();
```

If you want to get *column value by its name*, then use the following code:

```
String value = res.getColumnIndex("column_name");
```

Comment: let me try on monday when I am at office.

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors that need to be considered when retrieving data from a cursor; which row (position within the cursor) and then column and it's type.

To position the Cursor you use one of the Cursor's `move` methods. These are :-

- `move`, which moves the cursor relevant to it's current position.
- `moveToFirst`
- `moveToLast`
- `moveToNext`
- `moveToPosition` and
- `moveToPrevious`

All return true if the move could be performed otherwise false.

A cursor can be empty and have no rows, so `movetoFirst` would return false.

One of the more common usages is :-

```
while (cursor.moveToNext) {
    .... cursor action(s) here.
}
```

A Cursor will initially be positioned to before the first row i.e. it's position is -1 and can be set using `moveToPosition(-1)`.

The Cursor's `getPosition` method will retrieve the current position, noting that the first row is position 0.

Column's in rows are accessed according to the offset (which column) and the Cursor's `get????` (where ???? represents type) methods are used to retrieve the data from the row/column (there are other get.... methods e.g. `getPosition` as above). The  methods for retrieving the data are:-

- `getBlob` (retrieves a byte array).
- `getDouble`
- `getFloat`
- `getInt`
- `getLong`
- `getShort`
- `getString`

All take a single parameter, an integer that is the column's offset within the cursor (*which is not necessarily the offset in the table*).

You can use any on any type of data, with the exception of blobs. An attempt to use any, except `getBlob`, on a BLOB will result in an exception.

However, the results, can vary e.g. if you use `get`, for example assuming column with offset 0 contains ***rumplestilskin** then :-

- `cursor.getString(0)` will return ***rumplestiltskin***
- `cursor.getDouble(0)` will return 0 as a double.
- `cursor.getInt(0)` will return 0 as a float.
- .....

In short, **you should use the appropriate get method**, otherwise the results could be confusing.

Hard coding column column offsets, often results in issues therefore it is generally better to use column names in conjunction with the Cursor's `getColumnIndex` method. This takes a String, the column name, as a parameter and returns the offset of the column.

### Applying the above to the question:-

Code that could be useful (i.e. it retrieves data) could be :-

```
    Cursor csr = db.getData(myid);
    while (csr.moveToNext) {
         long id_of_the_row = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(yourDatabaseHelperClass.id));
    }
```

Noting:-

- `if (moveToFirst(myid)) { .... }` could be considered more correct but assuming that just a single row exists bot moveToFirst and moveToNext, as coded, produce the same result.
- Assuming that the id column is an alias of the rowid, then rowid is stored as a long and should properly be extracted as a long.
- yourDatabaseHelperClass.id will not be correct, rather you would replace it with the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper (the class that contains your `getData` method), it also assumes that variable **`id`** has **`public`** access.

### Links that may be useful or of interest:-

- [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
- [How flexible/restricive are SQLite column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types)

  - (includes examples of how some of the Cursor get???? methods retrieve data)
- [Are there any methods that assist with resolving common SQLite issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues)

Comment: let me try on monday when I am at office.