# How to store a date in a SQLite3 schema for Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am aware that 'datetime' is not a valid data type for SQLite, but I'm not quite sure what to replace it with. Take for example the following statements, would I store it as text like the others? If so, how would I then manipulate that later on, as a date?

```sql
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  title text not null,
  'text' text not null,
  date_created 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am aware that 'datetime' is not a valid data type for SQLite

SQLite's flexibility results in virtually any column type being valid e.g.

`CREATE TABLE weidrcolumntypes (column1 rumplestiltskin, column2 weirdtestcolumn, column3 etc)`

is valid and will create a table with 3 columns (4 with [rowid](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) column) :-

[image]

SQLite's flexibility also allows any value to be stored in any column (an exception being the [rowid](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), for tables that are not defined using `WITHOUT ROWID`, where the value must be an INTEGER).

A more comprehensive answer (tagged for Android but the principles still apply) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types).

[This may also be of interest](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

**So in  brief any column type would be able to handle/store datetime.**

> Take for example the following statements, would I store it as text
>   like the others?

As per above even as it is the code you have would be usable. You may wish to specify a column type of `TEXT` or `INTEGER`.

---

> If so, how would I then manipulate that later on, as a date?

As for storing date time, Integer, Long or String could be used, the latter having the complimentary [Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org./lang_datefunc.html).

As such, you could do much of the manipulation within your queries which would be language independent.