# Why this create table SQL work under sqllite3?

Tags: sqlite

I don't understand why this query (that is not correct) does not raise any error:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID, 
  VARIANT riri fifi lili,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID, VARIANT ASC))
```

Also is their any difference from:

```
  VARIANT TINYINT
  VARIANT INTEGER
  VARIANT BIGINT
  VARIANT UNSIGNED INTEGER
```

Comment: The answer to both of these questions is clearly explained in the SQLite [docs](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Did you not even _try_ to find the answer to this?

Comment: i didn't find where it's say the purpose to let user write VARIANT riri fifi lili whithout error ?

Comment: SQLite's default field type is VARIANT.  In fact, it's actually *harder* in SQLite to coerce fields to specific types.  I suspect your VARIANT clause (including all of your riri fifi stuff) is simply being ignored.

Comment: What's more. If you're using FireDAC, it has its own subset of [supported types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has a restricted set of column types (column affinity) (TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL and BLOB). However, it will accept virtually anything as a column type *(see How Flexible/Restrictive are SQLite column Types below)* and convert this according to a set of rules to one of the restricted set of column types:-

- If the column type contains INT then it will convert it to INTEGER.
- If the column type contains CHAR, CLOB or TEXT then it will convert it to TEXT.
- If the column type contains BLOB then it will convert it to BLOB.
- If the column type contains REAL, FLOA or DOUB then it will convert it to REAL.
- Otherwise it will convert it to NUMERIC.

So `riri fifi lili` will have a column type of NUMERIC *(drops through to the last rule)*.

`TINYINT`, `INTEGER`, `BIGINT`, `UNSIGNED INTEGER` will all have a column type of INTEGER *(as they all contain INT and meet the 1st rule)*.

`CHARINT` will have a column type if INTEGER (it meets the 1st rule).

Saying that a column can in fact contain any type, although the column's type (affinity) can have subtle nuances when retrieving data *(see Datatypes in SQLite3 below)*. *Note an exception to this is a column that is an alias of rowid.*

A more comprehensive answer can be found here [How flexible/restricive are SQLite column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types)

You may also wish to check out [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)