# Sqlite not using default values

Tags: python, sqlite

When using:

```
import datetime
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
c = db.cursor()
db.text_factory = str

c.execute('create table if not exists mytable (date timestamp, title str, \
    custom str, x float, y float, z char default null, \
    postdate timestamp default null, id integer primary key autoincrement, \
    url text default null)')
c.execute('insert into mytable values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', \
    (datetime.datetime(2018,4,23,23,00), 'Test', 'Test2', 2.1, 11.1))
```

I have:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: table mytable has 9 columns but 5 values were supplied

**Why doesn't SQlite take default values (specified during table creation) in consideration to populate a new row?**

(Also, as I'm reopening a project I wrote a few years ago, I don't find the datatypes `str`, `char` anymore in the sqlite3 doc, is it still relevant?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are saying that you want to insert all columns by not specifying the specific columns.

Change `'insert into mytable values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'`

to    `'insert into mytable (date, title, custom, x, y) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'`

Virtually any value for column type can be specified, the value will follow a set of rules and be converted to TEXT, INTEGER, REAL, NUMERIC or BLOB. However, you can store any type of value in any column.

- STR will resolve to NUMERIC,
- TIMESTAMP will resolve to NUMERIC,
- FLOAT will resolve to REAL,
- CHAR to TEXT.

Have a read of [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity) or perhaps have a look at [How flexible/restricive are SQLite column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to only supply values for some columns, you need to specify which columns. Otherwise the engine won't know where to put them. This line needs to be changed:

```
c.execute('insert into mytable values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', \
(datetime.datetime(2018,4,23,23,00), 'Test', 'Test2', 2.1, 11.1))
```

To this:

```
c.execute('insert into mytable (date, title, custom, x, y)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', \
(datetime.datetime(2018,4,23,23,00), 'Test', 'Test2', 2.1, 11.1))
```

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed that when using your solution, it's even not mandatory to create a table with `default null`: even if I remove all `default null`, it will still work with your solution, all these values will default to `None` anyway!

Comment: @Basj Yup. `Null` is the default default.

Answer (score 0):

#### Example Solution

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE vehicles_record (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)')
```

#### SQLite3 Query Above

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO vehicles_record(name) VALUES(?)", (name))
```

---

#### Result

> id would be 1, name would be value of name var, current timestamp for last column.