# Getting column size with JDBC in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

So I was wondering is there anyway I could retrieve column size in JDBC such as if the column type is varchar(5) it would return 5. I did some research and found out that SQLite ignore the size but I'm still dying to know is there anyway I could achieve this. I tried ResultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE") and also Databasemetadata.getColumnDisplaySize() but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **[length](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length)** function. However, that would be on a **per row basis**, as there no concept of a single column size; as each column per row has a specific size according to the value stored in the unique column/row combination.

- note that each column irrespective of it's declared type affinity can store any type of value in any type of column *(except for the rowid column and therefore an alias thereof)* and that the column type affinity itself can be virtually anything with some limitations. This is more comprehensively explained in [How flexible/restricive are SQLite column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557278/how-flexible-restricive-are-sqlite-column-types)

e.g.

```
SELECT length(mycolumn) AS column_size FROM mytable;
```

You could use the following to get the maximum length used. This utilises the **[max](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc)** function :-

```
SELECT max(length(mycolumn)) AS max_column_size FROM mytable;
```

- this would return 1 row i.e as the max function with just 1 parameter is an **[aggregate](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)** function and that the GROUP BY is effectively all rows, then there is effectively 1 GROUP, and thus 1 result is returned.
- you may find following the provided links useful e.g. **avg** may be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeT ! After some more research I found that you can get the data type using ResultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME") which return the data type as VARCHAR(5) or CHAR(3) etc. So I manage to resolve from there. But still thanks a lot for the useful information.